# Convert YYY-MM-DD to MON DD, YYYY in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-conversion

I am having difficulty converting dates in a column from YYYY-MM-DD to Mon DD, YYYY

I think I first need to reorganize the dates and then use a case when statement to specify 01 = Jan and so on? Is that correct?

```
SELECT to_date(column_name, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
FROM table
```

gives me some incorrect dates
i.e. previous = 2012-01-29 and
result from query = 0197-06-26

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
SELECT to_char(date(column_name), 'Mon dd, yyyy')
FROM table
```

gives me exactly what I need without the need of a case statement.

Comment: You shouldn't store dates as `varchar` or `text` to begin with. Please consider fixing your broken data model before you proceed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
This is just how the data was given to me for a project. I will fix it. Thanks